# Uploading Rotated Image to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, image-rotation

I'm try to accomplish the following task:

1. Selecting an image from Gallery
2. Rotating the image (if necessary) to the right orientation using ExifInterface
3. Upload the image to Firebase

### Question

If image requires rotation, i'll end up with a rotated Bitmap file. How do i convert this Bitmap file to an Uri so that i can upload to Firebase?

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == GALLERY_INTENT && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        mImageUri = data.getData();

        try{
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),mImageUri);
            rotatedBitmap = rotateImageIfRequired(getContext(), bitmap, mImageUri);
            mVideoImage.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap);
            imageHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
            imageWidth = bitmap.getWidth();

        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

private static Bitmap rotateImageIfRequired(Context context, Bitmap img, Uri selectedImage) throws IOException {

    InputStream input = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
    ExifInterface ei;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 23)
        ei = new ExifInterface(input);
    else
        ei = new ExifInterface(selectedImage.getPath());

    int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

    switch (orientation) {
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
            return rotateImage(img, 90);
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
            return rotateImage(img, 180);
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
            return rotateImage(img, 270);
        default:
            return img;
    }
}

private static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap img, int degree) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(degree);
    Bitmap rotatedImg = Bitmap.createBitmap(img, 0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    img.recycle();
    return rotatedImg;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To upload a bitmap into FireBase storage, you need to turn it into a byte array. You can do this by creating a ByteArrayOutputStream.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream boas = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
```

Then compress the bitmap into a format like JPEG or PNG. The compress method takes 3 parameters, the format, the quality, and the ByteArrayOutputStream.

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, boas);
```

Then create a reference to your FireBase Storage Reference, where you want to put the photo.

```
String imageFileName = "ExampleName";    
StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("images").child(imageFileName);
```

Here, I created a folder called 'images' and a file inside which is named using the previously created imageFileName String

Then I can upload it to FireBase using an UploadTask by saying

```
UploadTask task = ref.putBytes(data);
```

Using this task, you can create success and failure listeners.

```
 task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. I will try your method.